# Get new child object postion based on parent transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a function that calculates new OffSet position that takes 2 arguments old offset and rotation value (the rotation is only a float because the rotation is only happening around 1 axis always. I managed to find how to calculate facing direction based on rotation but I am having problem with offset. Found same topics like this but no answer except making child objects, which is not a good way. So a code like this

```
var offset = new Vector3(0f,5f,10f);
var rotationY = 90f;
var newOffset = NeededFunction(offset, rotationY);
```

The newOffset should be a Vector3 (10f,5f,0f). This is the funtion to calculate the facing direction

```
 private Vector3 GetFacingDirection()
{
    var rotY = transform.eulerAngles.y;
    var vector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotY, Vector3.up)
        * Vector3.forward;
    return vector;
}
```

Comment: what is offset and new offset?

Comment: lets say u have an object that is a child of other object. When parent has no rotation the child local position is offset. When parent rotates the child will also move and the new local position is new offset (that is what function should return).

Comment: I posted my answer, and would reccomend you edit the title of your question to "how to get child object position with parenting through transform" or something like hat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get `Quaternion.LookRotation` of the local position of the child game object. This is `childStartRot`. (Calculate in start, or only when you change it)
2. Get the magnitude (or distance from 0) of the **local** position of the child game object. You can calculate this by getting the `.magnitude` property of the child's local position. This is `childMag` (Calculate in start, or only when you change it)
3. Get total rotation of the *parent* **times** *child* **[this link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1353333/how-to-add-2-quaternions.html) explains how to add Quaternions (non-commutative)** rotation. This is `combinedRot`. (This updates every frame)
4. The point this rotation is "looking at" is equal to `Vector3.forward * combinedRot`. This is `pointOnRot`
5. Normalize `pointOnRot`. Then multiply `pointOnRot` by `childMag` to get the offset position.
6. The position of the child is equal to `pointOnRot` + the parent object's position.

Example script:

```
public Quaternion parentRot; //change whenever in play mode
public Vector3 parentPos; //change whenever in play mode
public Vector3 childPos;

Quaternion childStartRot;
float childMag;

void Start()
{
   Vector3 local = parentPos - childPos;
   childStartRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(local);

   childMag = local.magnitude;
}
void Update()
{
   Quaternion combinedRot = parentRot * childStartRot;
   Vector3 pointOnRot = Vector3.forward * combinedRot;

   pointOnRot = pointOnRot.normalized * childMag;

   Vector3 output = pointOnRot + parentPos;
   //set child object position to output.
}
```